# How to create custom user-id on the basis of users given info while registering in my android app?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, onclicklistener, android-spinner

[image]I want to add 3 inter-related spinner in my sign-up activity (for example, when 1 item is selected from 1st spinner with country name will reveal the 2nd spinner with area name and so on). Now I want to give unique id for every item of these spinners (id will not be shown in the spinner). When a user will select item from these 3 spinner, a user-id will generate on the basis of there selection. I want to keep a box(not editable by user) titled used-id. When the user will click that box to fill up, the generated user-id will reveal in that box. I am using firebase as my database.

I am new with android studio using java as my coding language. Please give me some idea on-

1. Where should I store spinner items with there respective IDs? (within the code or in to the firebase)
2. What process should be used to generate user ID?
3. How to create a un-editable box? Is onclicklistner enough for the reveal process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. you can store in firebase or local (strings.xml). 2. every 3 spinners have own id, example you can do, string1 + string2 + string 3 + databaseReference.push().key(). 3. enable = false

Comment: thanks for your reply. I added a image showing my requirements. please look at it and suggest me some solution.

Comment: As I said earlier, get them as string and if you want to store as int/long parse them.